# Pivotal Cloud Foundry: NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/HealthIndicatorRegistry

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I've been looking into updating a spring application from 2.2.0 to 2.7.5 and it compiles locally after the upgrade. But when I try to deploy to Pivotal Cloud Foundry I get an error on that vm instance. I've tried setting the health endpoint in the manifest and updating the spring security configuration. Here is the following stack trace on pivotal cloud foundry (PFC), any hint at where I should look would be great.

```
   2022-10-25T14:31:06.44-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT   .   ____          _            __ _ _
   2022-10-25T14:31:06.44-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
   2022-10-25T14:31:06.44-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
   2022-10-25T14:31:06.44-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
   2022-10-25T14:31:06.45-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
   2022-10-25T14:31:06.45-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
   2022-10-25T14:31:06.45-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT  :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.5)
   2022-10-25T14:31:06.71-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2022-10-25 18:31:06 [main] INFO  com.test.handshake.Application - Starting Application using Java 11.0.14 on ee17b509-ccd6-47d0-4aa1-fd46 with PID 16 (/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/classes started by vcap in /home/vcap/app)
   2022-10-25T14:31:06.71-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2022-10-25 18:31:06 [main] DEBUG com.test.handshake.Application - Running with Spring Boot v2.7.5, Spring v5.3.23
   2022-10-25T14:31:06.71-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2022-10-25 18:31:06 [main] INFO  com.test.handshake.Application - The following 2 profiles are active: "cloud", "dev"
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2022-10-25 18:31:09 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:134)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:319)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:572)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:419)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:137)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:109)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:447)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:268)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:325)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:147)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at com.test.handshake.Application.main(Application.java:15)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/HealthIndicatorRegistry
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:661)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.cglib.core.ClassLoaderAwareGeneratorStrategy.generate(ClassLoaderAwareGeneratorStrategy.java:57)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:358)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:585)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:110)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:108)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     ... 28 common frames omitted
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicatorRegistry
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:135)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   2022-10-25T14:31:09.90-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     ... 42 common frames omitted
   2022-10-25T14:31:10.25-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 1
   2022-10-25T14:31:10.25-0400 [CELL/SSHD/0] OUT Exit status 0
```

Gradle File:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
    id "org.flywaydb.flyway" version "6.5.7"
}

ext {
    set('springCloudServicesVersion', "3.5.0")
    set('springCloudVersion', "2021.0.3")
    set('springBootVersion', '2.7.5')
    set('metricsVersion', '2.1.1')
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-dependencies:${springCloudServicesVersion}"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
        mavenBom 'com.external.cloudnative:spring-base-dependencies:2.1.0'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("com.external.handshake:quest-shared:1.0.14")
    implementation("com.external.handshake:quest-solr:1.0.5")

    // Data
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-rest', version: "${springBootVersion}"

    // Web
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: "${springBootVersion}"

    // Logging
    implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.29'
    implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'
    implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-core', version: '1.2.3'

    // Lombok
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'

    //LDAP
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-ldap'
    implementation 'com.unboundid:unboundid-ldapsdk'

    // SRE
    implementation "com.external.mpp.pe.sre:metrics:${metricsVersion}"

    // Swagger
    implementation('io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0')
    //    implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-boot-starter', version: '3.0.0'

    //security
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-starter-config-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2:2.2.5.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
    implementation 'com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot-starter:2.1.2'

    // AWS
    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.11.682'

    //"commons"
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-exec', version: '1.3'
    implementation group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2.1'

    //cloud native
    implementation 'com.external.cloudnative:spring-base-app'
    implementation 'com.external.cloudnative:spring-base-api'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7'

    // Database
    implementation group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '7.0.0.jre8'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jdbc'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc', version: '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    implementation('org.flywaydb:flyway-core:6.5.7')
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-cache', version: '2.2.0.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'org.ehcache', name: 'ehcache', version: '3.9.3'
    implementation group: 'javax.cache', name: 'cache-api', version: '1.1.1'

    // Solr
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-solr', version: '2.2.0.RELEASE'

    // Mongo
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-mongodb'
    implementation 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.12.11'

    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    implementation('javax.validation:validation-api')

    // Testing
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testImplementation('org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher')
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api')

    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:4.8.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:4.8.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:4.8.0'
    implementation 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.12.17'

    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.9'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-testng-common:2.0.9'

    // Misc
    implementation 'org.json:json:20190722'
    implementation 'org.javatuples:javatuples:+'

    implementation 'com.github.seratch:jslack:3.4.2@pom'

    configurations {
        compileOnly {
            extendsFrom annotationProcessor
        }
    }

    test {
        maxHeapSize = "4096M"
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your dependencies (the pom or build file) to your quesiton. You are probably using incomatible classes or have some Spring Cloud stuff in there that pulls in different versions (Spring Cloud versions are tied to certain Spring Boot versions you need to upgrade both if you use that).

Comment: I've added the Gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Your dependencies ar quite a mixture. You have various versions of Spring Boot dependencies in your list of starters (like JDBC and cache for instance). The same for some of the Spring Cloud dependencies, so oyou are actually pulling in a mixture of versions. I suggest to clean up your build file to something like the following

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
    id "org.flywaydb.flyway" version "6.5.7"
}

ext {
    set('springCloudServicesVersion', "3.5.0")
    set('springCloudVersion', "2021.0.3")
    set('metricsVersion', '2.1.1')
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-dependencies:${springCloudServicesVersion}"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
        mavenBom 'com.external.cloudnative:spring-base-dependencies:2.1.0'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("com.external.handshake:quest-shared:1.0.14")
    implementation("com.external.handshake:quest-solr:1.0.5")

    // Data
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-rest'

    // Web
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation')

    // Lombok
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    //LDAP
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-ldap'
    implementation 'com.unboundid:unboundid-ldapsdk'

    // SRE
    implementation "com.external.mpp.pe.sre:metrics:${metricsVersion}"

    // Swagger
    implementation('io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0')
    //    implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-boot-starter', version: '3.0.0'

    //security
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-starter-config-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
    implementation 'com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot-starter:2.1.2'

    // AWS
    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.11.682'

    //"commons"
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-exec', version: '1.3'
    implementation group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2.1'

    //cloud native
    implementation 'com.external.cloudnative:spring-base-app'
    implementation 'com.external.cloudnative:spring-base-api'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7'

    // Database
    implementation group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '7.0.0.jre8'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-cache'
    implementation('org.flywaydb:flyway-core:6.5.7')
    implementation group: 'org.ehcache', name: 'ehcache', version: '3.9.3'
    implementation group: 'javax.cache', name: 'cache-api', version: '1.1.1'

    // Solr
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-solr'

    // Mongo
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-mongodb'
    implementation 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.12.11'


    // Testing
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testImplementation('org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher')
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api')

    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:4.8.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:4.8.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:4.8.0'
    implementation 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.12.17'

    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.9'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-testng-common:2.0.9'

    // Misc
    implementation 'org.json:json:20190722'
    implementation 'org.javatuples:javatuples:+'

    implementation 'com.github.seratch:jslack:3.4.2@pom'

    configurations {
        compileOnly {
            extendsFrom annotationProcessor
        }
    }

    test {
        maxHeapSize = "4096M"
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** The `spring-boot-starter-data-solr` doesn't exist anymore so if you really use that you need to replace that with manual dependencies instead, don't use an older version from Spring Boot as that will pull in older dependencies.

Comment: Why wouldn't keycloak be supported anymore? There is also a new Authorization server so I don't see that either. Solr will require some manual dependencies and you might want to reconsider its usage (see https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-solr).

Comment: I traced the error to version 2.4.0 when it initially happened.